# Simplest, Open Source Reporting Engine Recommendations

Tags: report, reporting

I'm currently investing Pentaho, Jaspersoft and Birt as possible reporting engines to integrate with the custom software my company develops.

I don't need ETL or OLAP style features.  Rather, I want a more productive wysiwyg report designer with a simple deployment option for embedding/deploying over the web.

Are there any recommendations out there that I'm missing?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Not open source, but [DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/), have an easy to use wysiwyg editor for both the report and the query, and let you embed the reports you create with the Web Report Widget function, the only downside: it run only on Windows, so depending of the platforms you want to deploy your custom software, it may not be useful for you.